How to store signed in user owned records using AWS Amplify & connected/autogenerated forms
I created a "Post" model & auto-generated CRUD forms on the AWS amplify studio for a nextjs/react project.
It has the following authorization rule on the GraphQL API
type Post @model @auth(rules: [{allow: owner}]) {}

Here is my implementation on React. The page is only accessible by a signed-in user.
Amplify.configure(awsExports);
export default function Post() {

  return (
    <Authenticator>
      <PostCreateForm />
    </Authenticator>
  )
}

Question: is there any modification that has to be made to the autogenerated form "PostCreateForm" component above  that will enable a post to be created with a "owner" foreign key or at best associate it with the signed in user?
